# Citrix Receiver Shuts down after opening Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: citrix

First question here.

I am new to ubuntu, and trying to use Citrix Receiver to open some launch.ica files from my university. However, when I open them, Citrix simply pops up in my Launcher, flashes a few times, and disappears again without warning or error.

I'm aware that this might be a vague question, my apologies, please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by re-hashing the certificates available to Citrix.

You may need to do this whenever they are updated.

```
sudo c_rehash /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/
```

Answer (score 0):

@Joris Van de Cavey
Still having the issue? May be you can enable connection logs on Receiver to troubleshoot the nature of the problem. To enable the collection of connection logs in Receiver:

1. Edit the /opt/citrix/ICAClient/config/AuthManConfig.xml with the following parameters as a user with administrator privileges:

   ```
   <key>TracingEnabled</key>
   <value>true</value>
   <!-- LoggingMode - none, normal, verbose -->
   <key>LoggingMode</key>
   <value>verbose</value>
   ```
2. Halt the following processes: AuthManagerDaemon, selfservice, ServiceRecord, storebrowse.
3. Start Receiver and connect to the store.
4. Check the logs under $HOME/.ICAClient/logs.

Ref: https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/receiver/linux/13-2/linux-about.html